# Apache Server suddenly 302'ing some sites

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

As the title states, some websites suddenly started out of the blue 302'ing in an endless loop. I have a setup with some (>4) active domains of which two are redirecting (main domain and another one). The redirect always links to the main domain of the server which is given in the reverse dns. I have absolutely no idea why this happens and would like to know where I can start searching for those ominous 302 redirects.

What I found out so far:
The redirects should not origin from the page content. I've deleted the main domain content and it still redirects. I also checked the htaccess and found nothing unusual in it. I checked the vhost configs of the domains and found nothing strange in them also. I restarted the server and the redirects persist. I only have an average knowledge so I would like to know where I could start searching for the 302 redirect commands in my config.

I am using a Debian Wheezy with Apache2, PHP and ISPconfig.

Comment: Well, either something changed or you have a compromised server.

Comment: How could I confirm the later? The logs didn't show anything special, guess I either don't know what to look for or they were altered...

Comment: Confirming a system compromise can be quite tricky. Anytime a system starts doing unexpected things, though, and you cannot easily determine the cause, you must consider that you've been a victim of some vulnerability.